How laziness works with applicative functors in Haskell?
I don’t quite understand how functions behave when working with applicative functors.
Here's an example:
ghci> (&&) <$> Just False <*> undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  undefined, called at <interactive>:6:25 in interactive:Ghci6

But if we don't use the Maybe context, then everything works as expected:
ghci> (&&) False undefined
False

Accordingly, the question is - why does this happen and is it possible to somehow avoid it?
How to ensure such behavior that if (&&) <$> Just False is encountered, the result of the function would immediately be Just False?

because it needs to know if the second one is a Just or a Nothing, if you would use (&&) <$> Nothing <*> undefined, you will not get an error.

Note that you also have (&&) <$> Just False <*> Just undefined which gives Just False.

The reason that the undefined in (&&) <$> Just False <*> undefined is evaluated is that the result depends on whether it is headed by a Just constructor or a Nothing:
> (&&) <$> Just False <*> Just False
Just False
> (&&) <$> Just False <*> Nothing
Nothing

If you want a function (&&^) :: Maybe Bool -> Maybe Bool -> Maybe Bool such that Just False &&^ Nothing evaluates to Just False, then you need to make use of the monadic interface for Maybe, not just the applicative one. That is:
(&&^) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
mx &&^ my = do
  x <- mx
  if x
    then my
    else return x

> Just False &&^ undefined
Just False
> Just True &&^ undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

((&&^) is available in the extra library.)
This illustrates the difference between the monadic and applicative interfaces: a monadic computation allows you to decide whether to run my or not based on the result of running mx, while an applicative computation requires you to specify all the computations in advance and then aggregate their results into one.
Compare this with the definition of liftA2 (&&) (using ApplicativeDo notation):
liftA2 (&&) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool
liftA2 (&&) fx fy = do
  x <- fx
  y <- fy
  pure (x && y)


This does not work because the value of undefined is relevant here. Indeed:
ghci> (&&) <$> Just False <*> Just undefined
Just False
ghci> (&&) <$> Just False <*> Nothing
Nothing

It thus has to inspect at least if it is a Nothing or a Just x, because that alters the path it has to follow.
As you see, you can use Just undefined, since indeed, a (&&) False does not need to know the second operand. But the applicative needs to know if it is a Nothing or Just x, since that determines if a Just False or a Nothing will be returned.
Haskell's laziness however more has to do how the functions are implemented. Indeed, (&&) is implemented as:
False && _ = False
True && x = x

if we would have implemented this as:
False && True = False
False && False = False
True && x = x

It will force evaluation of the second operand as well. So the laziness stems from the implementation of (&&), (<$>) and (<*>).
